# CSS3 :pseudo-class selector not working in Firefox 109

Tags: css, firefox, browser

I have the following CSS classes:

```css
.genre_element {
    background-color: none;
}

div.genre_element:has(input[type="checkbox"])::before {
    content: "\002B";
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

div.genre_element:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked) {
    background-color: #ff9400;
    transition: all .2s;
}

div.genre_element:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)::before {
    content: "\2713";
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is supposed to show a checkmark unicode character and add a bg-color to inputs as long is they are checked and add a plus character when they are unchecked. When they are unchecked they automaticaly revert back to the color I set in the `genre_element {}` class, which is `none`.

This works as expected in Edge, Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox I can't get it to work. I used caniuse.com to check my class for browser compatibility and enabled the `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` flag.
This fixes part of the problem as it displays the correct style that the buttons need to have when they are checked, but I cannot uncheck them. Clicking on them has no effect.

This is how the parent divs of the buttons look like before enabling the flag:

[image: buttons looking like their default state: having a bg-color of none and a "+" pseudo-element]

This is how they look like after enabling the flag; unchecking does not work:

[image: buttons looking like their checked state: having an orange bg and a "✓" pseudo-element]

This is how they look like in Chrome, Edge and Opera (desired outcome) after unchecking them:

[image: some buttons beeing checked and having an orange bg, and some beeing unchecked and having no bg]

Since enabling the flag causes the buttons to look like they are supposed to in their checked state, I am assuming that both the `::before` and the `:checked` are supported by Firefox (which corresponds to the information on caniuse.com and which I could confirm by looking into the developer console) but something else is causing the buttons to not work properly in firefox.

As a last resort I tried out adding this pseudo-class checking for the negation of the checked condition:

```
div.border_div_in_scrollbox:has(input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)) {
    background-color: none;
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

But this didn't fix the problem.

P.S.: After playing around a bit more I got firefox to show the desired state, but it is very buggy. Only sometimes after I select the input with the selector tool from the developer console, after I have unchecked it, does it change to the state it should have, but itt is not consistent at all. This is how it looks like (I made the original inputs visible again to make debugging easier):

[image]

Comment: Not that `:has` is a relatively new selector that is not fully supported yet! It is only supported by Firefox in the newest version with experimental mode activated.

Answer (score 2):

From what i can see on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) the [:has()](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) selector does not work with Firefox at all.
Had the same issue last week also and still looking for a :has() work around.[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)   `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements can not be used with input elements they can only be used with container elements like `div` or `span` you can wrap input element with div/span then use `:before` on div/span.

for more information

[can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that the `::before` pseudo-element is actually supposed to be inserted inside its target. Upon further investigation of the dev toos i noticed that the chromium browsers actually placed the element before the `<input>` while firefox did place it inside it, as it is supposed to. But I guess since originally pseudo-elements weren't supposed to work with inputs they create a bug and break the inputs, but chromium is smart enough to prevent this behavior by actually placing the `::before` element before the input.